# Можно ли завершить программу по истечении определенного времени в Python и как?

Tags: python, время

Мне надо завершить выполнение программы по истечении 5 секунд и вывести на экран 1. Со второй частью задания я справился, а с первой пока проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
t = time.monotonic()
while time.monotonic() - t < 5:
    print('выполнение программы')
print(1)
```